# Is this solution to $z = (\bar z)^3$ correct?

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to make sure that my solution is correct. We start with equation $z = (\bar z)^3$.

1. Magnitudes of both sides must be equal and also $|(\bar z)^3| = |\bar z|^3 = |z|^3$. Therefore $|z| = |z|^3 \implies |z| = 0$ or $|z| = 1$.
2. Angles of both sides must be equal. Let
   $$z = |z| (\cos \phi + i \sin \phi)$$
   where $\phi \in [0, 2\pi)$. Then because angle of $\bar z$ is oposite to angle of $z$
   $$(\bar z)^3 = |z|^3 (\cos (-3\phi) + i \sin (-3\phi)) \iff $$
   $$\phi \equiv -3\phi \pmod{2\pi} \iff $$
   $$4\phi \equiv 0 \pmod{2\pi} \iff$$
   $$ 4 \phi = 2k\pi\iff$$
   $$ \phi = \frac{k\pi}{2}, k \in Z.$$
   Now with assumption that $\phi \in [0, 2\pi)$ we can substitute $k =0, k = 1, k = 2, k = 3$ until we reach ends of $[0, 2\pi)$ interval to obtain all solutions for angle. The result is:
   $$\phi \in \{0, \pi/2, \pi, 3\pi/2\}.$$
3. There are 5 final solutions to initial equation:

- $z = 0$ or
- $|z| = 1$ and $\phi$ is one of four angles found in step 2.

Comment: That's correct (although I think it would be better to explicitly write complex values for $z$ for the second case). It can be simplified by multiplying both sides by $z^3$, which gives you $z^4 = |z|^3$, immediately getting that $z^4$ is real.

Comment: Instead of $z = |z| (\cos \phi + i \sin \phi)$, it is simpler to use $z = |z| e^{i \phi}$